# Is DATEVALUE() not supported in formula fields to be referred in Rollup summary field filter

Tags: formula-field, datetime, roll-up-summary

I have a formula field which references `MONTH(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate))`, but due to some reason this formula field is not visible in roll up summary field filter and I can't figure out the potential reason for it. I am not sure if we have any non deterministic fields or functions in the above formula. Can anybody guide me about a valid reason why this formula field is not visible in rollup summary and if there are any alternatives?

Comment: If you create a new custom field `CreatedDate_Month__c` and populate it in a Flow, then it will be available in the RSF

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the salesforce document.

> Automatically derived fields, such as current date or current user,
> aren’t allowed in a roll-up summary field. Forbidden fields include
> formula fields containing functions that derive values on the fly,
> such as DATEVALUE, NOW, and TODAY. Formula fields that include related
> object merge fields are also not allowed in roll-up summary fields.

See the [documention](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5)